# discord selfbot send the same message to different channels in different servers

Tags: discord, discord.py

I'm trying to create a macro that sends a message to different channels in different servers every 8h but I can't figure out how to make it send a msg in a channel automatic (I'm trying to send the msg as soon as I run the py file) I have been searching for different example in the discord.py documentation but all the examples I found send a msg after a command) but I just want to know how do I make a discord selfbot send a message that has multiple lines to a channel and then I believe I can make it myself.

Comment: Self-bots are 100% against the Terms of Service of the Discord API, you can have your account deleted for using one. https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Answer (score 2):

I know this should just be a comment but for the sake of making sure people will see this, I'm also posting it as an answer.:

Self-bots are 100% against the Terms of Service of the Discord API, you can have your account deleted for using one. https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/115002192352-Automated-user-accounts-self-bots-

Answer (score 1):

Put this in your code

```py
import time

@client.event
async def on_message(message):
    await message.channel.send('Text Here')
    time.sleep(28800)
```

and selfbots are against the tos and you can get your account deleted